# Вывод данных структуры

Tags: c, вывод, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct foo_predmet{
    char name[30];
    int score;
    int variant;
};

struct foo_gde{
    char name[30];
    char auditoriya;
    char vremya;
};

typedef struct foo_abitur{
    char fio[30];
    struct foo_predmet predmet[4];
    struct foo_gde gde;
    struct foo_abitur *next;
} abitur1;

abitur1 abitur[10];


int main(void){
    SetConsoleCP (1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(abitur[0].gde.name);
    printf("%s\n" abitur[0].gde.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Код программы. Вопрос, почему у меня выдает ошибку "expected a ')'"? Пробовал этот массив делать указателем и динамически память выделять, все равно

Comment: Выдает ошибку где? Номер строки и т.д. Каков полный текст ошибки?

Comment: Может, удалять такие вопросы, которые не несут никакой ценности, кроме информации, что ТС не читает сообщения компилятора?...

Comment: @Harry По идее, их надо закрывать как "не воспроизводится/опечатка". А отвечающих мягко бить по рукам за то, что отвечают на офф-топик вопросы.

Comment: @Harry Да, удалите, я сам пытался, но не смог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%s\n" abitur[0].gde.name);
```

Здесь пропущена запятая после формата. Надо так:

```
printf("%s\n", abitur[0].gde.name);
```

Comment: Ахахааххахаха, ломал голову дня два, спасибо))))